# how to get users data who replies,plusoners and resharers any google plus page?

Tags: google-plus

I have used this api

- https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/page-id/activities/public?key=app-id

and getting all public data of a particular google plus page and in that same json structure i get this

```
 "replies": {
     "totalItems": 0,
     "selfLink": "googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/replies-id/comments"
    },
    "plusoners": {
     "totalItems": 1,
     "selfLink": "googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/plusoners-id/people/plusoners"
    },
    "resharers": {
     "totalItems": 0,
     "selfLink": "googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/reshare-id/people/resharers"
    }
```

But when I call one of the above api i get this :

- "code": 403 "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.
  Continued use requires signup."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add your APIkey to the end of each of the URLs.

```
googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/plusoners-id/people/plusoners?key=app-id
```